# Googlemap - how to add and delete marker?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to place the marker when the user click on the google map, below is my code. It starts at this `-36.8484597,174.7633315`

```
    var map;
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-36.8484597,174.7633315);

    function initialize()
    {
        var mapProp = {
          center:myCenter,
          zoom:2,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         };

        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);

        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
          position:myCenter,
        });

        marker.setMap(map);

        // This event listener will call placeMarker() when the map is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            placeMarker(event.latLng);
        });
    }

    function placeMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location, 
            map: map
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

But when I click on the map, the marker does not show at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map variable is local to the initialize function. It is not available in the placeMarker function, unless you pass it in or remove the var keyword before it in the initialize function.

```
function initialize()
{
    var mapProp = {
      center:myCenter,
      zoom:2,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };

    map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7a9sxze/)

code snippet:

```js
var map;
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-36.8484597, 174.7633315);

function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapProp);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myCenter,
    });

    marker.setMap(map);

    // This event listener will call placeMarker() when the map is clicked.
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}

function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```